# TYPO3 migration from one server to another. Now can't log into backend

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, typo3, backend

I have taken over management of a very old TYPO3 instance 3.8.x. I had to migrate it from a very old server onto a new one. Old server php 4.x new server 5.x and I assume the mysql version is latest too.

Migration went surprisingly well, with only one image displaying differently.

Now, the problem is that I can't log into the backend.

I use correct username and password, javascript and cookies enabled. When I click log in, it takes a long time with the page loading icon, and then it goes to ERROR 500 - Internal Server error.

I've flushed caches, truncated old BE and FE user sessions (not that there are any FE users)...

The only thing I can think of is that the new web hosting settings are preventing me from logging into the backend? But with only error 500 to go by, I'm a bit stuck...

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated,

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the apache error log? Most of the time you'll find the related PHP error in there :)

Might be a problem of writing a session file, came across that myself recently.

Comment: Check the existence of typo3temp folder, check permissions.